# How can I set up this association and make calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Ruby: 2.0.**

**Rails: 4.0.1**

I have 2 models: `User` and `Orders` this is their relevant info:

- **User**

  - ID
- **Order**

  - user_id
  - distributor_id

And the relevant portions of my (current) models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :distributor, class_name: User
end
```

Basically, an User's orders are orders that they have placed, but each user also has "commissions" - and needs to be able to reference all of the orders that they are set as a distributor on. So:

```
user = User.find 7
user.orders // would return all orders where user_id = 7 (this works)
user.commissions // would return all Orders where distributor_id = 7 (this is what I need help with)
```

How do I set this up in the user model?

---

I think I may have been unclear earlier, here's a **tl;dr**:

- user.orders looks for Orders where user_id = user.id
- user.commissions looks for Orders where distributor_id = user.id

I need help setting up `user.commissions`

Comment: Try giving a foreign_key option like this `belongs_to :distributor, class_name: User, foreign_key: distributor_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :commissions, class_name: Order, foreign_key: :distributor_id
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :distributor, class_name: User
end
```

now call

`User.find(7).commissions`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - I ran into this: 2.0.0p247 :001 > User.first.commissions
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant User::Distribution

Comment: We are getting closer, but your update runs this query (from rails console):   `Order Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 22]]`  --- I need that to do a `where "orders"."distributor_id" = ?`

Comment: got it. alright - try adding the foreign key as I just updated my answer, that should give you what you need!

Comment: Nailed it - thanks for sticking with me through this one! (also thanks for being the only person out of the 3 answers that actually ready my question all the way through.)